# Running Ansible on a Raspbian installation, getting failed to get D-Bus connection

Tags: raspbian, systemd

The Ansible playbook does several things, but these are the ones I think are relevant to the problem:

- creates an account for user test
- enable lingering for that account
- copy script to `~/bin` and make service in `~/.config/systemd/user`
- `systemctl --user daemon-reload`
- flush_handlers
- enable services

It is during the enable services that I get the

> Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory

The enable services command are run with:

```
become: yes
become_user: "{{ user }}"
environment:
   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: "/run/user/{{ uid }}"
   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: "unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus"
```

After checking, I found that the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket` was not present. I did a touch to add it, and then I get

> connection refused

What is the proper way to set up a new user and enable scripts as services on Raspbian? I am running Raspbian 4.4.50-v7 on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+.

Comment: What happens when you the same sequence of commands of manually that are in the playbook? Have you tried `ansible-playbook --step?`

Comment: @MarkStosberg Thank you for your reply. both --step and doing it manually gives the same results, so I will need to investigate further into if the user account is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was to install `libpam-systemd` as the first step of the playbook.